# When my master lich levels up and becomes an Arch-lich, will it die if they have been genocided?

Tags: nethack

I've genocided Arch-liches and polymorphed my pet into a demilich. It has recently leveled up into a master lich. Will it become an Arch-lich, and if it does, will it die because I genocided them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out that it does die, unfortunately :(

This is the message produced when it levels up into an Arch-lich:

```
As the invisible <name> grows up into an arch-lich, he/she expires!
```

*sigh*. Should've genocided master mind flayers.

Things I've learned from this/things to note:

- This does *not* result in an alignment penalty (but we all know you did it)
- As soon as you see your pet get to the level before that genocided level, you should get it polymorphed (polymorph trap or wand, though I advise against wasting your polymorphing wand on this) so it doesn't "expire".